# IdentityServer4 + AddNegotiate implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4, kerberos

#### Question

I need implement Windows authentication on Ubuntu (kerberos) with IdentityServer4.

I took [IdentityServer host project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/IdentityServer4/host).

I added handler AddNegotaite to Startup:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddNegotiate();
```

And created WindowsController with `[Authorize]` attribute:

```cs
[Authorize]
public class WindowsController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Challenge(string returnUrl)
    {
        return await ChallengeWindowsAsync(returnUrl);
    }

    private async Task<IActionResult> ChallengeWindowsAsync(string returnUrl)
    {
        var wp = HttpContext.User;
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback", "External"),
            Items =
            {
                { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                { "scheme", "Negotiate" }
            }
        };

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity("Negotiate");

        // the sid is a good sub value
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, wp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value));

        // the account name is the closest we have to a display name
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));

        // add the groups as claims -- be careful if the number of groups is too large
        var wi = wp.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

        // translate group SIDs to display names
        var groups = wi.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        var roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value));
        id.AddClaims(roles);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(id),
            props);
        return Redirect(props.RedirectUri);
    }

}
```

After Windows sign in page redirect to External/Callback.
And authentication crash in Callback method on this line:

```cs
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, localSignInProps);
```

with error:

> InvalidOperationException: sub claim is missing
> IdentityServer4.Extensions.PrincipalExtensions.GetSubjectId(IIdentity identity) in PrincipalExtensions.cs, line 81

It crashes because IdentityServer tries create session and crash when it tries get `sub` claim from WindowsIdentity. But WindowsIdentity has not this claim.

How to fix it? I did not find any solution IdentityServer4 + AddNegotiate.

My sample project:
[WinAuth.zip](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/files/5629560/WinAuth.zip)

Need to go: http://localhost:5002/External/Callback

I guess identityserver cannot create session with

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddNegotiate();
```

#### Solutuion:

In startup:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddNegotiate();
```

And I changed `[Authorize]` attribute to

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```